# Using Weka for unsupervised clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, unsupervised-learning

I have data in the following format:

```
X,Y,sim(X,Y)
```

That is, a list of triples, with:

- X, the name of an object;
- Y, the name of another object;
- sim(X,Y), a real number expressing the distance between the two objects.

Now, I want to apply some unsupervised clustering algorithm on this data.
I had Weka in mind but I would gladly consider alternatives too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of algorithms that can work with similarity matrices:

- Hierarchical Linkage Clustering
- DBSCAN
- OPTICS
- Affinity Propagation
- Spectral Clustering

just to name a few. As for software, I prefer [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/), it has much much more clustering choices.